# Are JavaScript and C++ too similar to learn at the same time?

Tags: javascript, c++, scripting

I'm new to both web design and programming. I started learning C++ about four months ago and I just started learning web design about a week ago.

Even though I've been doing web design for only about a week I feel that I am more than proficient in XHTML, so I decided after XHTML I'd learn JavaScript and then HTML5.

The reason I started to learn web design is because I wanted to learn something new, but because I only started C++ four months ago I didn't want to confuse myself by learning another programming language.

The problem now is that I started learning JavaScript and saw that the syntax seems kind of similar to C++. I realize that one is a scripting language and the other is not, but my question is: for someone with my experience would this be too confusing? Or will I be fine learning them both at the same time?

Comment: They're completely different languages. That said, if you're new to programming, I'd stick to learning your first language one at a time.

Comment: Don't be fooled by syntax. Most languages that share C's syntax are wildly different. It's the semantics and the idioms that matter.

Comment: Javascript and C++ are similar only at very first glance. They are incredibly different languages.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I have observed many people saying the word "syntax" without really knowing what it actually means. More often than not, they confuse it with "semantics".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't be fooled. After four months of C++ and a week of HTML you are proficient in neither.

Your direction depends on which way you want to go. C++ is pretty much useless in the area of web design.

If you want to design web sites then stick with the HTML that you know and learn it inside out. Supplement that with CSS when you feel ready and lastly JavaScript.

If you want to write generic applications then pursue C++ and learn about all of its possible environments and applications.

Once you can confidently answer most questions on a subject that appear on Stack Overflow then you can consider yourself proficient, but please don't under-estimate the task: it will take you many years

Comment: Well I was saying that I am proficient in xhtml. I know that I'm no where near proficient in C++. And I plan on following through and going to school for C++ for sure, but I just wanted to learn web design mostly for fun and I understand that C++ isn't used for webdesign.

Comment: Writing HTML used to mean you could slice a page up into rectangles using `<table>` elements. More recently CSS will do all that and more for you. HTML + CSS + JavaScript, in that order, is what you must learn if you intend to make money designing web sites. On the other hand you might consider Java if you want to be generally useful. It is probably the most common language, and its platform independency means you would be useful on all of Linux, Mac, Windows, iOS and Android platforms. I don't think I would recommend C++ to anybody; it is painful to use and is really for specialist markets

Comment: Well I've been learning C++ for 4 months now and I don't plan on stopping, I've already invested so many hours in learning it. Also I love the capabilities that it has. And I thought by saying I knew x html my knowledge of CSS was implied.

Comment: Knowledge of HTML doesn't imply CSS any more than it implies JavaScript, XSLT, MySQL or PHP. It is simply a markup language that lets you describe the *data* to be presented to a browser. C++ is really not that special, and you have to fight hard to get a working program out of it. Don't get me wrong, I spent fifteen years using C and C++ and know them inside out, but I avoid using them wherever I possibly can. Four months really is nothing, and by now you know barely ten percent of the language and its intricacies. If you're not committed to web programming then *please* consider Java

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to programming, then stick to C++ right now. Otherwise Javascript and C++ should be easy to learn together, most of the syntax is same except *object orientation*. Some nuances of Javascript might seem a little odd for someone working with C++. I personally think both can be learnt together.

Comment: Alright, well I was just wondering if I can learn C++ and java-script at the same time without getting confused. But if you say they can be I'll give it a try. Thanks.